# Package Manager for $HOME

Tags: package-manager, dependencies

I search for a package manager which works in $HOME (per user) on linux systems.

For me a proper dependency management is important:

1. I tell the package manager that I want to install "foo" in version V.
2. The package manager scans all dependencies (recursive)
3. Then the package manager tries to solve the dependency graph.
4. If there is a conflict in the graph: fail, and tell me what's wrong.
5. If the graph can be solved: go ahead and install.

The above algorithm was already implemented several times (RPM, dpkg, ...), but AFAIK they all don't work on a per user basis in $HOME.

Comment: There are specialized package managers like Maven that work in $HOME. Do you want a package manager that can work with any type of program? Does it need to be popular, or are you prepared to create packages yourself?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes, it should work with any type of programm. At least any type of command line or programming tool for linux. GUI or MS-Windows is not needed. About "popular": I don't care if it popular or not.

Comment: Do you require the package managers for helping you with programming or those which simply version controls the install system of a software

Comment: @AloyASen I don't know what you mean with "helping you with programming". I am programming with pyCharm, Python, Django, PostgreSQL on Linux. The package manager should install the created software. Does this answer your question? Next "which simply version controls the install system". I do version control with git. ...